# Where did this question go?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

Yesterday I was reading through the responses to "[what is the best programming paper you have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868507/what-is-the-best-programming-paper-you-have-read)".  I left the tab on my browser open & hit "refresh" today to see what the latest answers are.  To my surprise, the page has disappeared!  I get the standard "Page Not Found".

[Even Google indexed the question](http://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+the+best+programming+paper+you+have+read) (still indexed as of right now).  Where did this question go?  Why can't I see it anymore?  There were some fantastic answers that I'd like to look at in more detail!

I tried searching via StackOverflow's search bar & Google, but I couldn't find anything...

Comment: *raises hand*  I flagged this question for merging into its dupe.

Comment: See related feature request here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-a-question-is-merged-redirect-original-question-url-to-new-one-automaticall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it got merged with "[What are your favorite programming-related academic papers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358033/what-are-your-favorite-programming-related-academic-papers)"

Comment: And there is no auto-linking happening in this case?

Comment: @gf: There's never auto-linking when questions are merged.  This is why we typically like to leave questions closed as duplicates around, so they stay linked to the original.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to have questions either link to their merged targets, or just auto-redirect there? I didn't even know question merging existed, I always assume when that happens a question got deleted