# Question gone into the void (not visible even for 10K users)

Tags: support, specific-question, meta, deleted-questions

While going through [those revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1195/revisions) I saw this:

> [image]

It did not say the duplicate target which is suspicious by itself so I clicked the [link still available in the old revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21727/topic-tag-specific-faq-pages) just to be greeted with... waffles. And not the user.

Any dev can shed some light on the destiny of that poor question? Has Jeff hard deleted it from the database for some reason?

Comment: It was probably merged with something else. Back in the day, merges effectively nuked the original post.

Comment: @yoda makes sense. Any way to confirm this without dev intervention?

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50702/160166) and Bill's answer should be proof enough, I suppose. It no longer behaves this way, so it's not reproducible. Coming to think of it, this is a duplicate of that. It's your call whether to close it or to delete it :)

Comment: @yoda thanks, dunno about duplicate as we're dealing with specific questions and there still might be other explanation.

Comment: Ah, finally we got the "Migrate to the void" option!